Can I download content of email from yahoo without using outside app? Part of my automation testing
I'm not able to download the content of email as html from yahoo mail. Using selenium C#.
Also, Can I use Selenium C# for opening email and then download email C# in same project?
Control S or Right click and Save as option is not working

What's the intention of using a browser automation tool for Yahoo mail over using POP3/IMAP?

you should add more details and code you've tried here.  But the webdriver does have a method for getting page source.
